# How to store a symmetric matrix?

Tags: language-agnostic, matrix

Which is the best way to store a symmetric matrix in memory?

It would be good to save half of the space without compromising speed and complexity of the structure too much. This is a language-agnostic question but if you need to make some assumptions just assume it's a good old plain programming language like C or C++..

It seems a thing that has a sense just if there is a way to keep things simple or just when the matrix itself is really big, am I right?

Just for the sake of formality I mean that this assertion is always true for the data I want to store

```
matrix[x][y] == matrix[y][x]
```

Comment: Look at this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9040526/380384) that can help in storing a symmetric matrix into 1D array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I find that many high performance packages just store the whole matrix, but then only read the upper triangle or lower triangle.  They might then use the additional space for storing temporary data during the computation.

However if storage is really an issue then just store the `n(n+1)/2` elements making the upper triangle in a one-dimensional array.  If that makes access complicated for you, just define a set of helper functions.

In C to access a matrix `matA` you could define a macro:

```
#define A(i,j, dim) ((i <= j)?matA[i*dim + j]:matA[j*dim + i])
```

then you can access your array nearly normally.

Comment: This seems a good solution, let me do some tries before accepting :)

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding the macro. Is the macro used to to access elements from the 1D array?

Comment: @Rajath, I think that given a square matrix with `dim` rows, `A(i, j, dim)` returns the index of `i,j` in a 1D array.

Comment: The macro is inaccurate, as it may attempt to access elements outside the defined range n(n+1)/2.

Comment: @Ale the macro is accurate it always reads from upper triangular submatrix. There is no intent to make it use `n(n+1)/2` storage.

Comment: This answer does not what the question asks "It would be good to save half of the space"

Answer (score 24):

Here is a good method to store a symmetric matrix, it requires only N(N+1)/2 memory:

```
int fromMatrixToVector(int i, int j, int N)
{
   if (i <= j)
      return i * N - (i - 1) * i / 2 + j - i;
   else
      return j * N - (j - 1) * j / 2 + i - j;
}
```

For some triangular matrix

```
0 1 2 3
  4 5 6
    7 8
      9
```

1D representation (stored in `std::vector`, for example) looks like as follows:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

And call fromMatrixToVector(1, 2, 4) returns 5, so the matrix data is vector[5] -> 5.

For more information see http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/algorithms/general/article.php/c11211/TIP-Half-Size-Triangular-Matrix.htm

Comment: Ben Axelrod's article (which you cite) has some nice ASCII diagrams of the triangular array and what it looks like in 1D.  Maybe you could copy them into your answer?  They helped me visualize this.

Comment: Added matrix visualization.

Comment: The first expression can be rewritten as `(2*N - i - 1)*i/2 + j`

Answer (score 1):

Well I would try a triangular matrix, like this:

```
int[][] sym = new int[rows][];
for( int i = 0; i < cols; ++i ) {  
     sym=new int[i+1];
}
```

But then you wil have to face the problem when someone wants to access the "other side". Eg he wants to access [0][10] but in your case this val is stored in[10][0] (assuming 10x10).

The probably "best" way is the lazy one - dont do anything until the user requests. So you could load the specific row if the user types somethin like print(matrix[4]).

Comment: Shouldn't that be `sym[i] = new int[i + 1]`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a one dimensional array the code would look something like this:

```
int[] new matrix[(rows * (rows + 1 )) >> 1];
int z;
matrix[ ( ( z = ( x < y ? y : x ) ) * ( z + 1 ) >> 1 ) + ( y < x ? y : x ) ] = yourValue;
```

You can get rid of the multiplications if you create an additional look-up table:

```
int[] new matrix[(rows * (rows + 1 )) >> 1];
int[] lookup[rows];
for ( int i= 0; i < rows; i++)
{
   lookup[i] = (i * (i+1)) >> 1;
}
matrix[ lookup[ x < y ? y : x ] + ( x < y ? x : y )  ] = yourValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using something that supports operator overloading (e.g. C++), it's pretty easy to handle this transparently. Just create a matrix class that checks the two subscripts, and if the second is greater than the first, swap them:

```
template <class T>
class sym_matrix { 
    std::vector<std::vector<T> > data;
public:
    T operator()(int x, int y) {
        if (y>x)
            return data[y][x];
        else
            return data[x][y];
    }
};
```

For the moment I've skipped over everything else, and just covered the subscripting. In reality, to handle use as both an lvalue and an rvalue correctly, you'll typically want to return a proxy instead of a T directly. You'll want a ctor that creates `data` as a triangle (i.e., for an NxN matrix, the first row will have N elements, the second N-1, and so on -- or, equivalantly 1, 2, ...N). You might also consider creating `data` as a single `vector` -- you have to compute the correct offset into it, but that's not terribly difficult, and it will use a bit less memory, run a bit faster, etc. I'd use the simple code for the first version, and optimize later if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a staggered array (or whatever they're called) if your language supports it, and when x < y, switch the position of x and y. So...

Pseudocode (somewhat Python style, but not really) for an n x n matrix:

```
matrix[n][]

for i from 0 to n-1:
    matrix[i] = some_value_type[i + 1]

[next, assign values to the elements of the half-matrix]
```

And then when referring to values....

```
if x < y:
    return matrix[y][x]
else:
    return matrix[x][y]
```

Comment: Is the "reffering to values" supposed to be in a wrapper function like this one return-value getElement(x,y)? (I don't know Python)