# Make efficient - A symmetric matrix multiplication with two vectors in c#

Tags: c#, performance, vector, matrix, matrix-multiplication

As per following the inital thread [make efficient the copy of symmetric matrix in c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039189/make-efficient-the-copy-of-symmetric-matrix-in-c-sharp) from cMinor.

I would be quite interesting with some inputs in how to build a symmetric square matrix multiplication with one line vector and one column vector by using an array implementation of the matrix, instead of the classical

```
long s = 0;
List<double> columnVector = new List<double>(N); 
List<double> lineVector = new List<double>(N); 
//- init. vectors and symmetric square matrix m

for (int i=0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j < N; j++){
        s += lineVector[i] * columnVector[j] * m[i,j];
    }
}
```

Thanks for your input !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line vector times symmetric matrix equals to the transpose of the matrix times the column vector. So only the column vector case needs to be considered.

Originally the `i`-th element of `y=A*x` is defined as

```
y[i] = SUM( A[i,j]*x[j], j=0..N-1 )
```

but since `A` is symmetric, the sum be split into sums, one below the diagonal and the other above

```
y[i] = SUM( A[i,j]*x[j], j=0..i-1) + SUM( A[i,j]*x[j], j=i..N-1 )
```

From the other posting the matrix index is

```
A[i,j] = A[i*N-i*(i+1)/2+j]  // j>=i
A[i,j] = A[j*N-j*(j+1)/2+i]  // j< i
```

For a `N×N` symmetric matrix `A = new double[N*(N+1)/2];`

In `C#` code the above is:

```
int k;
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    // start sum with zero
    y[i]=0;
    // below diagonal
    k=i;
    for(int j=0; j<=i-1; j++)
    {                    
        y[i]+=A[k]*x[j];
        k+=N-j-1;
    }
    // above diagonal
    k=i*N-i*(i+1)/2+i;
    for(int j=i; j<=N-1; j++)
    {
        y[i]+=A[k]*x[j];
        k++;
    }
}
```

Example for you to try:

```
| -7  -6  -5  -4  -3 | | -2 |   | -5 |
| -6  -2  -1   0   1 | | -1 |   | 21 |
| -5  -1   2   3   4 | |  0 | = | 42 |
| -4   0   3   5   6 | |  1 |   | 55 |
| -3   1   4   6   7 | |  7 |   | 60 |
```

To get the quadratic form do a dot product with the multiplication result vector `x·A·y = Dot(x,A*y)`

Comment: Thanks for this pretty detailed answer and for providing the code, I have learned a lot in few lines.

Comment: Just a small confirmation on my understanding. In this particular case using a square symmetric matrix we can consider both vector as column vectors (that we can name x & x'). Meaning that if I want to have multiplication result for both vectors, I can do it in one go by using for "below diagonal" code as y[i]+=A[k]*x[j]*x'[j];  and so on for "above diagonal". Am I correct ?!

Comment: Well you wouldn't consider both `x` and `x'` in the same operation. So the statement `y[i]+=A[k]*x[j]*x'[j]` is _not_ valid. Maybe you need to include an example in the original posting on what you are trying to do. Typically you do something like `scalar = x'*A*x`.

Comment: Consider also that the product of two symmetric matrices is not symmetric.

Answer (score 4):

You could make matrix multiplication pretty fast with unsafe code. I have [blogged about it](http://bratched.com/en/home/dotnet/48-fun-with-matrix-multiplication-and-unsafe-code.html).

Comment: Correct. If the goal is speed, unsafe is the way to go. If the object is reduced size, then the reduced element approach referenced in OP is the way to go.

Comment: I wonder how `unsafe` compares to the packed array in my post. The naive approach in your blog uses a 2D array which is notoriously slow and is to be avoided. The fastest approach is jagged arrays, then packed arrays and then native 2d arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Making matrix multiplication as fast as possible is easy: Use a well-known library. Insane amounts of performance work has gone into such libraries. You cannot compete with that.