# Optimizing an adjacency matrix creation from a 2D array of nodes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cluster-analysis, adjacency-matrix

I am attempting to create an adjacency matrix from a 2D array of nodes. The adjacency matrix will be passed to a program that will cluster the nodes either through

1. Spectral clustering algorithm
2. Kmeans clustering algorithm

**Node class **

```
    public class Node{
    public int _id;
    public bool _isWalkable;
    public int _positionX;
    public int _positionY;
    public Vector3 _worldPosition;
    }
```

**Grid Class**

```
    public class Grid : MonoBehaviour
    {

        void CreateGrid()
        {
        grid = new Node[_gridSizeX, _gridSizeY];
        Vector3 worldBottomLeft =  transform.position - 
        Vector3.right * worldSize.x / 2 - Vector3.forward * worldSize.y / 2;

        //set the grid
        int id = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < _gridSizeX; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < _gridSizeY; y++)
            {
                Vector3 worldPosition = worldBottomLeft + Vector3.right * 
                    (x * _nodeDiameter + _nodeRadius) + 
                    Vector3.forward * (y * _nodeDiameter + _nodeRadius);
                //check to see if current position is walkable
                bool isWalkable = 
                    !Physics.CheckSphere(worldPosition, _nodeRadius, UnwalkableMask);

                grid[x, y] = new Node(isWalkable, worldPosition, x, y);
                grid[x, y].Id = id ++;

            }
        }
        totalNodes = id;
    }
}
```

Nodes are stored inside a 2D array called grid and represent a walkable path for a character to move on. I have succesfully implemented an A* algorithm with a euclidean distance heuristic. What I would like to do is cluster these nodes using the aforementioned clustering algorithms, but first I need to create an adjacency algorithm for them. This is the best pseudocode I could come up with

```
    int[][] _adjacencyMatrix = new int[gridSizeX*gridSizeY][gridSizeX*gridSizeY];

    for(int x = 0; x < gridSize;x< XgridSize; i++)
    {
         for(int y = 0; y < gridSize;y< YgridSize; i++)
         {
           if( !Grid[x][y]._isWalkable)
              continue;
           Node n = Grid[x][y];
           List<Node> neighbors = GetNeighbors(n);
           for(int k; k<neighbors.Count(); k++)
            {
                _adjacencyMatrix[n._id][neighbors[k]._id]=1; 
            }
         }
    }

    public List<Node> GetNeighbours(Node n)
    {
        //where is this node in the grid?
        List<Node> neighbours = new List<Node>();

        //this will search in a 3X3 block
        for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
        {
            for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
            {
                if (x == 0 && y == 0)
                    continue; //we're at the current node

                int checkX = n._positionX + x;
                int checkY = n._positionY + y;

                if (checkX >= 0 && checkX < _gridSizeX && checkY >= 0 
                    && checkY < _gridSizeY)
                {
                    if(grid[checkX, checkY]._isWalkable)
                        neighbours.Add(grid[checkX, checkY]);
                    else
                        continue;
                }
            }

        }
        return neighbours;

    }
```

**My main concern**

My main concern with this is the total complexity of the above algorithm. It feels like it's going to be heavy and I have a total of (75^2 = 5625) nodes in a adjacency matrix that will be 5625X5625 in size! There must be a better way to find the neighbors than this, is there?

Comment: Shoudn't you be checking n.isWalkable() somewhere?

Comment: kmeans doesn't use pairwise distances.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix is symmetric, so you only need to save half of it, see ([How to store a symmetric matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187957/how-to-store-a-symmetric-matrix)) for an example. The matrix values are binary, so saving them as booleans or in a bit vector will cut down memory by a factor of 4 or 32, respectively.

Alternatively, since the check for two adjacent nodes takes constant time (`abs(n1.x - n2.x) <= 1 && abs(n1.y - n1.y) <= 1 && grid[n1.x, n2.x].isWalkable() && grid[n2.x, n2.y]`), you could just pass the clustering algorithm a function which checks for adjacency on-the-fly.

Answer (score 0):

5k by 5k is not very large. 100 MB is something you can keep in memory. If you want to avoid this cost, do not use algorithms based on distance matrixes!

However, since your similarity appears to be

d(x,y) = 1 if adjacent and both nodes walkable else 0

your results will degenerate. If you are lucky, you get something like connected components (which you could have gotten much easier).
Pairwise shortest paths would be more useful, but also more expensive to build. Maybe consider solving this first, though. Having a full adjacency matrix is a good starting point I guess.

k-means cannot work with pairwise distances at all. It needs distances point-to-mean only, for arbitrary means.

I suggest to look at graph algorithms, and spend some more time understanding your objective, before trying to squeeze the data into clustering algorithms that may be solving a different problem.