# How to get i, j -th element of symmetric matrix using operator[]

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, operator-keyword

I have a symmetric matrix, represented as in this question ( [How to store a symmetric matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187957/how-to-store-a-symmetric-matrix) ). And I need to get i, j elements of it using overloaded operator[]

In the question above there are some options with methods, but not operator. So, I tried to search for something else. I saw, how to do this thing on a common matrix, but there is no information about matrix, represented in vector

```cpp
int fromMatrixToVector(int i, int j, int N)
{
   if (i <= j)
      return i * N - (i - 1) * i / 2 + j - i;
   else
      return j * N - (j - 1) * j / 2 + i - j;
}
```

```cpp
template<typename T, int M, int N>
class SimMatrix
{
private:
    T a[N / 2 * (N + 1)];
    int k;

public:
    SimMatrix();
    //**************
    class Row{
    private:
        SimMatrix *m;
        int i;
    public:
        Row(SimMatrix *m, int i);
        T& operator[] (int j)
    };

    SimMatrix::Row operator[] (int i)
    {
        return Row(this, i);
    }
    //**************
...
    Row operator[] (int i);
   };
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Pleas show us the matrix class you have written.

Comment: @Beta
```c++

template<typename T, int M, int N>
class SimMatrix
{
private:
    T a[N / 2 * (N + 1)];
    int k;
public:
    SimMatrix();
    //**************
    class Row{
    private:
        SimMatrix *m;
        int i;
    public:
        Row(SimMatrix *m, int i);
        T& operator[] (int j)
    };

    SimMatrix::Row operator[] (int i)
    {
        return Row(this, i);
    }
    //**************
    Row operator[] (int i);
...
};

```

Comment: @Beta sorry that it is without newlines, idk how to do it in comments

Comment: @Beta if it will be better, here it is on Pastebin https://pastebin.com/AwaJmW0S

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code