# Matrix where columns store the same information as rows - Efficient way to store

Tags: c, algorithm, storing-data, storing-information

I have a 168x168 matrix, each element is a 16bit variable, it happens that the values of each row correspond to the same values on the same column, so column 1 has the same values as row 1 and so on and so forth.

I would benefit from having a smaller memory footprint and it seems there is some duplicated information there but I cannot think of any way to store that same information in a smaller matrix/array.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187957/how-to-store-a-symmetric-matrix) related question?

Comment: No, I hand't seen it, I guess that answers my question. Thanks for the tip!